# ¿Como configuro mi servidor en cpanel?

Tags: php, html, mysql, cpanel

Tengo el problema de que subí mi sistema a un servidor de pruebas en el hosting de host gator, y mi sistema funciona excelente ya que debe subir mas de quinientos archivos pdf al mismo tiempo, pero al momento de cargarlo al servidor de HTS que es donde va a quedar realmente ya no me permite cargar mas de 20 archivos, ya probé poniendo un archivo php.ini en la carpeta del proyecto, y un archivo .htaccess con las siguientes configuraciones:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 600M
php_value post_max_size 600M 
php_value max_execution_time 900 
php_value max_input_time 900
php_value max_file_uploads 1024
```

Donde en el servidor de prueba con el archivo **php.ini**, funciona bien, pero en el **HTS** ya no.

Me pueden ayudar en esto por favor, alguien que sepa donde esta la configuracion del archivo **php.ini en el cpanel de HTS**. Gracias

Comment: saludos, la mayoria de hostings se debe crear un archivo php.ini en tu proyecto para que ese cambio afecte a dicho proyecto con las configuraciones necesarias

Comment: ¿Qué es HTS? ¿Es otro proveedor? Con "cargar archivos" ¿te refieres a subir un archivo desde la página a un PHP que los recibe? ¿Subes todos a la vez o consecutivamente uno tras otro?

Comment: sí, es otro provedor, pero no reconoce mis archivos .htaccess ni el archivo php.ini que yo agregue en mi proyecto. mientras que en el servidor de host gator funciona bien..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En hostgator, en el panel de configuración, tienes una opción para modificar directamente el php.ini

Aquí tienes un video con los pasos a seguir:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPylmbYEURU

De todas formas, ten en cuenta que aparte de la configuración de php.ini también tienes otros factores que te pueden afectar.
En principio las configuraciones de Apache, aunque creo que en hostgator eso no está limitado.

Y por otro lado, tengo en cuenta el bandwith de tu plan de hosting, si tienes mucho tráfico, te quedarás sin servicio muy rápido.
Para más información:

https://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-policies/payment-fees/bandwidth-policy-and-prices

Comment: Para ayudar a futuros visitantes y evitar que tu respuesta pierda validez si algún día ese vídeo no está disponible deberías transcribir los pasos descritos en el vídeo en tu respuesta (y, además, ganarte votos positivos).